# Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I got this error and I am not sure what it's about. The last thing I remember doing is adding a `clearInterval()` method to clear some `setTimeOut()` intervals variables. Besides that I am not sure what it could be. Not asking for a solution, but if anyone knows any possibilities of what could trigger that error, maybe that might help me to figure out where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

An infinite loop can cause this error. You are into a function that never ends and since everything is freezed, the player let you interrupt the running script after a timeout period.

Answer (score 1):

Nine times out of ten it's something like this:

```
var i:int;

while (i < 10)
{
    // do something
}
```

i.e. you probably forgot to increment `i`,